# Why is repeated sub-object navigation faster than using a short-hand variable?

Tags: javascript, performance, object, reference, shorthand

Sorry that I didn't know how to properly phrase the question, but here's the issue:

```
var o = {
    my: {
        very: {
            deep: {
                sub: {
                    fn(x) {
                        return x + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var n = 0;

//without short-hand function
var timeStart = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    n += o.my.very.deep.sub.fn(i);
}
var timeEnd = performance.now();
console.log(timeEnd - timeStart);

n = 0;

//with short-hand function
var fn = o.my.very.deep.sub.fn;
timeStart = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    n += fn(i);
}
timeEnd = performance.now();
console.log(timeEnd - timeStart);
```

The question is: Why is the code in the first loop 5-7% faster (when executed in global scope), though it has to repeatedly go down the sub objects, while in the second loop, it uses the short-hand `fn` instead?

PS: If you find a better question title, feel free to edit.

Comment: For me the second loop is twice as faster than the first.

Comment: If you take a look at the comments below @vlaz' answer, we've already talked about that this might for some reason be dependent on the browser resp. its JS engine.

Comment: "this might for some reason be dependent on the browser" --- this is not a joke?

Comment: @zerkms I was probably too unspecific: The above code containst two different approaches to solve the same problem. I expected one to more efficient ("faster") than the other, because of a (seemingly simple) logical difference between the approaches. But I did not expect that it depends on the engine, which of these approaches is faster. That doesn't make sense to me. And by "faster" I mean by a distinct margin, which is about the same on each repetition.

Comment: "That doesn't make sense to me." --- then you need to check optimising compilers. If modern engines did not optimise code - it would run orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var o = {
    my: {
        very: {
            deep: {
                sub: {
                    fn(x) {
                        return x + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var n = 0;

//without short-hand function
var timeStart = performance.now();;
for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    n += o.my.very.deep.sub.fn(i);
}
var timeEnd = performance.now();;
console.log(timeEnd - timeStart);

n = 0;

//with short-hand function
var fn = o.my.very.deep.sub.fn;
timeStart = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    n += fn(i);
}
timeEnd = performance.now();
console.log(timeEnd - timeStart);
```

Running this (note the usage of `performance.now()` instead of `Date`) the seems to be a very small margin of difference between the two. On some runs the first implementation will be (very very slightly) ahead, in some the latter. Without an isolated test environment it might as well be as good as you can get but, in essence, this level of testing will show you that there is very little, if any, difference between the two approaches.

Comment: For me, the first one is always ahead by roughly 5-7%, being something like 8,300ms vs. 8,700ms. If you wrap it into a function, JS optimization its in and `i` needs to be much larger. Still, the first one is ahead by roughly 1%. But I don't care about the margin, just the fact that something seemingly less efficient is actually more efficient.

Comment: Note that it also depends on the JS engine - on Firefox, the second one seems to be faster more often than not - perhaps around 60-70% of the time.At any rate, even a 8,300ms vs. 8,700ms means nothing, since the execution time will not be constant anyway - it's within negligible boundaries. Also, in this case the function is a noop - the JS engine might have optimised that away anyway, so you're not even testing "executing a function" but just straight iteration. Simply put, this test doesn't really show anything.

Comment: I've tested this in [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) (with clear cache and without addons). When I wrap it into a function and add 3 zeros to `i` (to get a reasonable time), the results are in fact considerably close. Executed in global scope though, the first loop is _always_ faster, no matter how often I re-execute the code.

Comment: Since you're testing this in a browser, I assume it's for a publicly available application. Your users will not be running Firefox Developer Edition and without addons. I'm typing this on normal Firefox with a reasonable amount of addons and for me they run in a completely inconclusive manner. I just tried it in Chrome and the first one is _significantly_ slower. I'm talking _five times_ slower - 40ms vs 8. Re-running keeps these keeps the results consistent - first approach stays around 36-45ms and the second one at 8-9ms. Edge gives me 40-45ms vs 30-35ms.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, I have neither Chrome nor Edge installed right now. But this is a rather strange phenomenon since I'd expect some logic in terms of efficiency here. But if it's really dependent on the engine whether the first or second loop is faster, then I really don't understand how JavaScript handles even basic constructs like sub-objects in this case.

Comment: As I said, the JS engine itself will do some optimisations. It seems completely possible that both the traversal and the "shorthand" will result in the exact same code being executed. And with the function doing nothing, it might actually have been removed from the end execution. Or not - again, depends on the engine. Still, it might be that the performance you're seeing is purely an empty `for` loop.

Comment: Just to make sure, I added some "dummy" operations to the code to avoid such potential code removals as you described. At least in Firefox Developer Edition nothing changed.

Comment: Updated my snippet. Please use `performance.now()` because it _is_ meant for measuring performance. `new Date()` is not accurate enough. At any rate - Firefox 13 vs 12 ms. Difference is around 1ms or less - negligible. Edge ~58-60 vs ~45-48ms. First one is around 30% slower. Chrome ~80-100ms vs ~42-50ms. First approach takes just about twice as long as the second.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is faster because you are not doing property lookup on each iteration.

on the first one, you are saying go to o then my then very then deep then sub then execute the function `o.my.very.deep.sub.fn(i)` for every iteration

but on the second one you are caching the `fn` up top with `var fn = o.my.very.deep.sub.fn;` now it does not have to do the lookup for `fn` in each iteration, avoiding extra work

some engines like v8 do inline caching for optimizations, they might not even do dynamic lookups for each iteration but it all depends on the implementation. check this to understand how v8 implements it. [fast property access](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design%20Elements#fast-property-access) also [how v8 optimizes property access](https://gist.github.com/twokul/9501770) but the takeaway is that

> V8 is generally pretty optimistic about your code and tries to speed
>   it up as much as it can. But sometimes the assumptions that it makes
>   are not valid (a hidden class wasn't the one expected). In this case,
>   V8 will replace Inline Cache fast path code with full non-optimized
>   code.